# Why does SQL Server convert VARCHAR to DATETIME using an invalid style?

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I can't make out from [the documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx) why SQL Server parses a text in a format other than the specified style.

Regardless of whether I provide text in the expected format:

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, N'20150601', 112)
```

or incorrect format (for style `113`):

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, N'20150601', 113)
```

The results are the same: `2015-06-01 00:00:00.000` I would expect the latter to fail to convert the date (correctly).

What rules does it employ when trying to convert a `VARCHAR` to `DATETIME`? I.e. why does the latter (incorrect format style) still correctly parse the date?

**EDIT**: It seems I've not been clear enough. Style `113` should expect `dd mon yyyy hh:mi:ss:mmm(24h)` but it happily converts values in the format `yyyymmdd` for some reason.

Comment: You are returning the DATETIME, not a textual representation of the DATETIME, so the style is irrelevant.  If you want to see the style doing something then CONVERT the DATETIME back to a VARCHAR again, e.g. SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(20), CONVERT(DATETIME, N'20150601'), 113)

Comment: Maybe a implicit conversion is taking place before the actual convert?

Comment: Deleted my answer, but `When expression is a date or time data type, style can be one of the values shown in the following table`. You have **not** got a datetime expression.

Comment: Conversion using 112 format returns an ISO format string which is `yyyymmdd` by default while 113 format return Europe default format and also contains milliseconds.Also the link says that the expressions at position 2,3 must be any  hexadecimal character from 0-9 and a-f.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because the date is in a canonical format ie(20150101). The database engine falls over it implicitly. This is a compatibility feature.

If you swapped these around to UK or US date formats, you would receive conversion errors, because they cannot be implicitly converted.

EDIT: You could actually tell it to convert it to a pig, and it would still implicitly convert it to date time:

```
select convert(datetime,'20150425',99999999)
select convert(datetime,'20150425',100)
select convert(datetime,'20150425',113)
select convert(datetime,'20150425',010)
select convert(datetime,'20150425',8008135)
select convert(datetime,'20150425',000)
```

And proof of concept that this is a compatibility feature:

```
select convert(datetime2,'20150425',99999999)
```

Although you can still implicitly convert datetime2 objects, but the style must be in the scope of the conversion chart.

Comment: Good spot. This is because you're adding styles to the date string.

Comment: My point is that it is not converted implicitly as yyyyMMdd format

Comment: by it I mean yyyy-MM-dd is not converted implicitly to datetime as yyyMMdd does.

Answer (score 1):

Reason why is the date `N'20150601'` converted to valid datetime is because of fact that literal `N'20150601'` is universal notation of datetime in SQL Server. That means, if you state datetime value in format `N'yyyymmdd`', SQL Server know that it is universal datetime format and know how to read it, in which order.

Comment: Styles apply to `NVARCHAR` and `VARCHAR` equally. Try `SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, N'03/06/2015',113)` to see that the style is being applied.

Answer (score -1):

You should convert to `varchar` type in order to apply those formats:

```
SELECT CONVERT(varchar(100), CAST('20150601' as date), 113)
```

OK, you are converting `datetime` to `datetime`. What did you expect? In order to apply formats you should convert to `varchar` and you have to have date or time type as second parameter.

Comment: My question is why it does convert *to `DATETIME`*, not how it's displayed.